# Understanding how Models and Forms affect one another and database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am creating form for users to input information too. I then want to save that information to a database and be able to extract information.

I am having difficulty however when I try to create a drop down list and multiple selection list. For example say I define a model as in my `models.py` file as such:

`gi_category = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=GI_NOGI)`

Where I have `GI_NOGI` specified as

`GI_NOGI = (('GI','GI'),('NOGI','NO-GI'))`

My `forms.py` looks something like this

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
     weightclass = forms.ChoiceField(choices=WEIGHTCLASS, required=True,label='Weight Class')
     gi_category = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=GI_NOGI, label='Contest You Intend to Enter', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=True)

class Meta:
    model = Register
    fields = ['name', 'age', 'birthdate', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip',
              'phone', 'email']
    labels = {'name':'Name', 'age':'Age on April 21', 'birthdate':'Birth date',
              'address':'Address', 'city':'City', 'state':'State', 'zip':'Zip',
              'phone':'Phone', 'email':'Email'}
    widgets = {
        'birthdate':forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'MM/DD/YYYY'}),
        'phone':forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '(###)-###-####'})}
```

Now I believe I am overwriting the gi_category and weightclass from models somehow because I cant access their respective values in the database. I don't know how to create a SelectMultiple any other way than I had I did(If this is problem any insight would be great.

I am wondering what I am doing wrong?

Also on a related note I want to have a database value for gi_category in which it can either have values of 'NO-GI' or/and 'GI'

I am saving the form values using this `views.py`

```
WEIGHTCLASS = (
                ('MFYW','Men Fly Weight(129 lbs. & Under)'),
                ('MBW','Men Bantan Weight(130 lbs. to 139.9 lbs)'),
                ('MFEW','Men Feather Weight(140 lbs. to 149.9 lbs.)')
)

GI_NOGI = (('GI','GI'),
            ('NOGI','NO-GI') 
)

class Register(models.Model):
    """register some text"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    birthdate = models.DateField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    weightclass = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=WEIGHTCLASS)
    gi_category = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=GI_NOGI)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string represenation of the model."""
        return self.weightclass
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possibly to save the output of a `forms.MultipleChoiceField`  to a `models.CharField`. What would that look like? I think you'll need to either add a third option to your `GI_NOGI` choices (which consists of both) or else write that as a separate model and link via `models.ManyToMany`.

Comment: @ChidG That makes sense. How then do you save multiple values to a single model?

Comment: You can save a list of integers in a charfield like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.validate_comma_separated_integer_list, or use CommaSeparatedIntegerField in older versions of Django, (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield) but it's a kinda hacky way to do it. I would recommend writing `GI_NOGI` as a separate model and using a `ManyToManyField` to link to `Register`.